# Visual Studio Code on Raspberry Pi 4 -- Interpereter path changes from 3.7.3 to 3.8

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, raspberry-pi4

I installed vs code on my raspberry pi 4 and I have both python 3.7.3 and 3.8 installed. I have set the default to 3.8 however in visual studio code when I change the interpreter from 3.7.3 to 3.8, the install packages do not load [pylint import error] and I can't see to re-install them to the new directory  "/usr/local/bin/python3.8" -- I have looked for the file where this might be but cant find  "%HOME%\pip\pip.ini", as others have suggested -- as this location does not exist.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to check the python environment variables of your system, and then select the interpreter you want to use. reference:[this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/).

As for the pylint error, it is recommend that you install it again under the python 3.8 interpreter.

In addition, you could try to use [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) to run python programs Pertinently;

If it doesn't work, hopefully you could show more details.

Comment: Thanks -- I am going to try this as I have to re-install the OS after uninstalling python. I will update

Comment: Ye this problem has been solved as I re-installed again. --thx